# Generalization of Implicit Function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

Let $f\colon \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^m$, $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m \ni (x, y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ be continuously differentiable. The implicit function theorem guarantees, under certain conditions, that if there exists a point $(a, b) \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m$ such that $f(a, b) = 0$, then in a neighborhood $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ of $a$ there exists a $g \colon U \to \mathbb R^m$ which is continuously differentiable and satisfying $f(x,g(x)) =0$. In practice, this guarantees that we can write $y = g(x)$, at least locally.

I am wondering whether it is possible to obtain a similar result for a function $f\colon \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$. If I find a point $(a,b)$ as above such that $f(a, b) = 0$, is it possible, at least in some neighborhood of $a$, to write $y = g(x)$? If yes, under which conditions?

Comment: This is no answer, but intuitively I would say no, i.e., either no such $g$ exists or no "natural choice" of $g$ exists. Intuitively, the implicit function theorem gives you a parametrization of an $n$ dimensional zero set obtained by "cutting out" $m$ equations. So, here you are cutting out 1-equation, and asking for an $n$ dimensional parametrization of something much larger. As an example, consider the projection onto the last coordinate, then for $m > 1$, there is no natural choice of $g$. But again, this is no answer, just my thoughts on the problem, I may be wrong.

Comment: I see what you mean. The example of the projection onto the last coordinate is very clarifying. Maybe, though, some existence result for $g$ can be obtained (without uniqueness)

Comment: True, here's something else that could work. Having obtained $(a, b)$ fix some $m-1$ coordinates of $b$ and restrict the function to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, then you can apply the usual implicit function theorem. Although, I suppose one has to be careful which coordinates are kept fixed. And this might apply more generally $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to \mathbb{R}^k$ for $1\leq k\leq m$.